# How to replace/transform/expand String in java

Tags: java, hashmap, switch-statement

I have a method which maps a given string to another string like if the input to the method is "RS256" it will return "SHA256WithRSA" and many more. My method is given below

```
public String getAlgorithm(String alg) {

    // The internal crypto provider uses different alg names

        switch(alg) {
            case "RSA256" : return "SHA256withRSA";
            case "SHA384" : return "SHA384withRSA";
            case "SHA512" : return "SHA512withRSA";
        }
        throw new Exception("Not supported");

}
```

is there any other way to do this (i don't want to use **MAP**). I'm looking to see if there is any design pattern or any OOP concept to do this.

Comment: `i don't want to use MAP`. Ah ..my eyes ..Where is map here ?

Comment: Enum types could be used to map 'alg' to the returned string as well.

Comment: why you don't want to use Map?

Comment: Using `Map` will be easier and quite efficient for your code.

Comment: Be specific and reasonable. why you can't use `Map`.

Comment: Its just because my instructor want me to find another method.

Answer (score 1):

Use real map, I mean `java.util.Map` which keeps key-value pair ex. `Map<Key,Value>`

```
Map<String,String> map= new HashMap<String,String>();
map.add("RSA256","SHA256withRSA");
map.add("SHA384","SHA384withRSA");
map.add("SHA512","SHA512withRSA");
...

public String getAlgorithm(String alg) {
     return map.get(alg);
}
```

Comment: Now I can see a Map here. :)

Answer (score 1):

You are actually written a Facade Pattern here, I think you are wrapping some kind of library. switch-case statement should be fine.
Using map introduces overhead, so better no to use it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `if-else` to check `alg` equals to your condition and return value similar to this. But current way is very similar to this.

Why you can't use `Map`? that is the better way.

```
Map<String,String> algoMap=new HashMap<>(String,String);
```

Now you can put `algoMap.put("algoName","Value")`

Answer (score 0):

Use HashMap

```
HashMap<String, String> newMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
newMap.put("RSA256", "SHA256withRSA");
newMap.put("SHA384", "SHA384withRSA");
newMap.put("SHA512", "SHA512withRSA");
String value = (String) newMap.get("RS256");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use enum types as well, but either way you have to use a switch statement without maps.

```
enum Algorithm {
   RSA256,
   SHA384,
   SHA512;

   public String name(String pValue) throws Exception {
      switch(this) {
         case RSA256:
         return "SHA256withRSA";
         case SHA384:
         return "SHA384withRSA";
         case SHA512:
         return "SHA512withRSA";
         default:
         throw new Exception("Not supported");
   }
 }

}
```